# How to change svg path width on hover

Tags: css, svg, path

I have an issue I can't find an helpful answer. I have a svg arrow, the arrow has to grow when the user hovers over with the mouse. The problem is that only the line has to change size not the arrow head. I just want the line to grow horizontally.
This is the svg code

```
<svg width="51" height="8" viewBox="0 0 51 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M50.3536 4.35355C50.5488 4.15829 50.5488 3.84171 50.3536 3.64645L47.1716 0.464466C46.9763 0.269204 46.6597 0.269204 46.4645 0.464466C46.2692 0.659728 46.2692 0.976311 46.4645 1.17157L49.2929 4L46.4645 6.82843C46.2692 7.02369 46.2692 7.34027 46.4645 7.53553C46.6597 7.7308 46.9763 7.7308 47.1716 7.53553L50.3536 4.35355ZM0 4.5H50V3.5H0V4.5Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

And this is the code the I have working right now

```
svg {
    width: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

svg:hover {
    width: 100px;
}
```

I also have a Codepen link
https://codepen.io/godhandkiller/pen/xxRZeYv

The problem here is that I'm manipulating the whole SVG but I only need to change the like size.

Comment: You can't. The path includes the arrow head so it can't be affected separately. You would need a second path being *just* the arrow head to do that.

Comment: Your SVG path is not a stroke. [SVG stroke-width Property](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_stroking.asp)  [Example](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/ZEBWXaz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution: you can use a line path with a marker-end. The marker is the tip of the arrow. For the animation I'm using SMIL animations changing the d attribute of the path from `M1,4L25,4` to `M1,4L50,4`. The animate element has a begin attribute making the animation to begin when you mouse over the overlaying rectangle: `begin="theRect.mouseover"`. Another animate element animates the path on mouse out: `begin="theRect.mouseout"`

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg id="theSVG" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51 8" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round">
  <defs>
    <marker id="m" overflow="visible" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M-3,-3L0,0 -3,3" />
    </marker>

  </defs>

  <path d="M1,4L25,4" marker-end="url(#m)">
    <animate attributeName="d" to="M1,4L50,4" dur="1s" begin="theRect.mouseover" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    <animate attributeName="d" to="M1,4L25,4" dur="1s" begin="theRect.mouseout" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
  </path>

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="none" pointer-events="all" id="theRect" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need it, I just had to play around with the values. I notice that the "hover" action is inside the svg, is there a way to change that so it's the parent div instead? The issue is that since the arrow is too small it's hard to trigger the animation

Comment: The animation is triggered when you mouse over the overlaying transparent rect. This rect is covering all the svg element. Also: since the svg elemet has a viewBox attribute and no width, is taking the whole width available covering all the parent element